# JsLinb: How to convert a JSON to jsLinb code

Tags: javascript, json

How may I convert a JSON code to a jsLinb code and post it to the code editor in order to draw the widgets like text filed.

What I'm doing is a storing the JSON code that is generated from the jsLinb UI builder in database and when the user return back he can retrieve his work on jsLinb UI builder.

I already figured out how to store the JSON code but I'm not able to convert it back to jsLinb code and generate the widgets again.

Here is jsLinb UI builder website:
http://www.linb.net/VisualJS/UIBuilder.html

jsLinb website:
http://www.linb.net/